# BreezeJS: Check if ANY entities has validation errors

Tags: breeze

I have a use-case where I want to access whether or not ANY entities within my BreezeJS EntityManager has validation errors. Basically a "hasValidationErrors" on the EntityManager.

The use-case is simply that I want to disable a "Save changes" button on the UI, and since I am using the Angular Binding system it should be a fast operation.

To me, it seems that this does not exist, and am wondering if there are any simple workaround or any actual ways of accomplishing it.

The closest I've come is the following:

```
    var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager(
        {
            serviceName: "/breeze/Model/"
        });

    var errorCount = 0;
    mgr.validationErrorsChanged.subscribe(function (validationChangeArgs) {

        var added = validationChangeArgs.added;
        if (added) {
            errorCount += added.length;
        }

        var removed = validationChangeArgs.removed;
        if (removed) {
            errorCount -= removed.length;
        }
    });
```

And then using errorCount to see if there are any validation errors. But this approach does not take into consideration if an entity is detached when it has validation errors. (For example through a call to rejectChanges() on the EntityManager).

It also feels like a very "hackish" approach.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation on validation? http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a fast way to do this. It's such an unusual case that I rather doubt we'd  implement special logic for this.

Detaching an entity does clear the validation errors. Have you confirmed that it doesn't raise the `EM.validationErrorsChanged` event? Bummer.

In any case, your approach does seem a bit brittle.

One way to short circuit the test is to check first if the EM has changes. If it doesn't, there is no point in checking for validation errors because you can only save changed entities (invalid unchanged entities don't matter).

Here's some code for your `datacontext` that might work for you (not tried or tested but the ideas are there):

```
datacontext.enableSave = em.hasChanges();      // should bind to datacontext.enableSave
datacontext.checkEnableSave = checkEnableSave; // can call at will
datacontext.suspendEnableSaveChecking = false  // as explained

// potentially reset flag when hasChanges changes
// or when validationErrorsChanged
em.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(checkEnableSave);
em.hasValidationErrorsChanged.subscribe(latchedCheckEnableSave );

function checkEnableSave () {

    datacontext.enableSave = em.hasChanges();
    if (!datacontext.enableSave) return; // no changes -> disable save

    // changes pending; only enable if no validation errors
    var changes = em.getChanges();
    for (var i = changes.length; i--;) {
        if (changes[i].entityAspect.hasValidationErrors) {
            datacontext.enableSave = false; // so sad
            return; // look no further;  we're done.
        }
    }        
}

// can disable validation error checking when you know
// that there will a flurry of validation changes
function latchedCheckEnableSave () {
    if (!dataContext.suspendEnableSaveChecking) {
        setEnableSave();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I was worried that the app might enter a phase of rapid validation checking which could trigger a perf killing cycle of validation error checks across many entities with pending changes. By offering a suspend toggle, the developer can put off the evaluation until a quiet time and then force the check

I'm not sure if you have to worry about `$scope.$apply()`. I'm pretty sure everything involved here is synchronous.

Comment: Is this really such an unusual case? I can imagine many situations where one might want to save all changes made in an EntityManager as a batch, and wanting to a expose a "Save changes" button that only should be enabled if there are no validation errors. 

Anyway, I found that if you subscribe to the "entityChanged" event on the EntityManager, you can actually listen to if it is on action "EntityAction.Detach" and if it is remove its "getValidationErrors().length" from the count I described above. Now I'm just worried that entityChanged is called on every keystroke so it must be super fast.

Comment: I fear you might have to worry about how often this is called. That's why I put the latch in there; it's entirely possible that this would be called too often.

Comment: Is it a common scenario? This is the first I've heard of it. In fact, I'd be afraid of it. Suppose an entity that I cannot see is invalid. As a user I'd be staring at the screen, looking at a clean entity with changes and I'm wondering "why can't I push the Save button? I HATE this app!"  Disabling the button is not a good enough UX IMO. You have to give the user a clear idea of what is wrong and what to do. Until I understand this better it's hard for me to get enthusiastic about your proposed feature. Convince us :-)

Comment: The issue is probably derived from my lazy nature. I have a few different controllers that all show sets of different entities, which can be edited. In these views I am using the zValidate directive to display error messages, so the user is warned of validation errors. BUT, I don't want to incur the overhead of having to write code to check if all these different entities are valid in each controller, and would rather simply be able to ask, are there currently any errors on the EntityManager. The alternative would be subscribing the hasValidationErrorsChanged on each entity in my controller.